Blazor scoped CSS scopes are not the same as the ones from the HTML elements
I have a blazor page Page.razor and a css file for that page Page.razor.css. These files used to be in Components/Pages but I recently moved them into a subfolder of Pages. Now blazor generates different css scopes in the css file than for the html elements.
(This only happens when the app is hosted on a server (azure web app in my case). It works fine while I'm running it locally)
This is what's in my HTML document after starting the app:
<div class="chat" b-o6nfzu7aoq>

And this is what's in the css file:
.chat[b-dzcshse1ta] {...}

I've tried rebuilding, checking wether the link to {AppName}.styles.css in App.razor exists and creating a new css file for the page.

I am guessing your namespaces don't align. The .razor always generates code with the namespace of the folder unless you use the @namespace attribute. Other than try a clean & rebuild and clear your browsers cache.

@BrianParker
I don't understand what you mean with the namespaces. I don't use the namespace attribute in that page and I've already tried cleaning and rebuilding the solution and clearing the browser cache which all didn't work.


Now blazor generates different css scopes in the css file than for the
html elements.

Using CSS isolation, within the bundled file, each component is associated with a scope identifier. For each styled component, an HTML attribute is appended with the format b-{STRING}, where the {STRING} placeholder is a ten-character string generated by the framework.
At build time, a project bundle is created with the convention obj/{CONFIGURATION}/{TARGET FRAMEWORK}/scopedcss/projectbundle/{ASSEMBLY NAME}.bundle.scp.css.
So, for your issue, you can try the following:

Delete the obj folder and Re-build the application.
Clear the browser cache.


I have tried that already and it does not fix the problem.

@Schlafhase Can't reproduce the problem. Can you create a minimal sample to reproduce the problem and then share it?

I can't reproduce it either but one important thing i forgot to mention is that the issue only occurs when the application is hosted (on an azure web app). It works fine when running it locally. @ZhiLv
